How can I fix a hole in my drywall around the corner bead?
Damage was done to the drywall near the bullnose corner bead which created a hole and caused the area on and around the corner bead to crack. The drywall behind the right side of the corner bead no longer firmly supports it within the damaged area.
What can I do to repair the hole and damaged area so that it has the necessary support for the corner bead? What materials should be used to repair it?



Is that layering we see a deliberate texture or the result of earlier damage?

It was actually a deliberate texture by the original homeowner.

The drawback to round bead, and really any plastic bead, is that it's fragile. It's not intended to be fully supported from below. That's the tradeoff for style.
Here's what I'd do.

Scrape and chip away all loose material. You have to open this bag of worms to fix it.

Turn off the relevant circuit breaker, then remove the cover plate for the switch and dismount the switch. Wrap the screw body with tape and tuck it inside the junction box so it doesn't protrude.

Resecure any loose corner bead flange. You want to solidify it without deforming it. Use drywall nails or similar to get all the flange edges snug.

Prefill, ideally with setting-type compound, which doesn't shrink as much and doesn't block progress for days. Press into all voids firmly, and scrape the face flush. There should be almost nothing to sand at this stage.

Sand or scrape lightly with your taping knife to knock off any crumbs, then skim. Taper out onto the wall with a wide knife, at times held vertically along the bead, and at times horizontal. This results in a flatter finish.

Repeat the last two steps until you have things fully filled and flat. Then sand lightly, prime, and paint.



You'll need a two inch drywall blade and some joint compound. Break away any lose or cracked old joint compound from the area. Apply the joint compound from the center of the damaged area up and down to the smaller areas so there's firm pressure into the ends. Use the corner edge as a straight edge. Work the area until you have a smooth fix. Wait about 15 to 20 minutes and then run a clean paint roller over the area lightly to give it a little texture. Fix any other imperfections in the wayll the same way. Touch up with paint if you've got leftovers or repaint the entire wall if needed.
